# Can I watch dev ghosts I've beaten?

Tags: offspring-fling

Once you get close enough to the rainbow flower time, you get to see a dev ghost performing the dev time as you play. Once you *beat* the rainbow flower time, the dev ghost stops appearing. This can be annoying if you want to watch the ghosts again, or if you beat a dev time without ever seeing the dev ghost.

Is there any way to get the dev ghosts back, besides wiping your save or something?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, if you get 100%, you unlock a button to turn all dev ghosts back on. I'm not sure whether the requirement is actually 100%, or slightly easier; I unlocked the button when I hit 100%, but I got the last rainbow flower on my first clear of the last level, so it might unlock when you get all blue flowers or all gold flowers or something.